# Failed to update the Synchronization Target on all available CD environments

Tags: web8, content-manager

We are upgrading from Tridion 2013 sp1 to Web8 . After upgrade we are not uble to update the synchronization target. CME throws below error

```
Failed to update the Synchronization Target on all available CD environments.
 at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Topology.TopologyHelper.UpdateTopology(SynchronizationTarget synchronizationTarget)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.SynchronizationTargetDal.Update(SynchronizationTarget synchronizationTarget)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.SynchronizationTarget.Save()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.Model.Services.SynchronizationTargetsManagerImpl.SaveSynchronizationTarget(SynchronizationTarget synchronizationTarget, XmlElement synchronizationTargetXml, Boolean doneEditing)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.Model.Services.SynchronizationTargetsManagerImpl.SaveSynchronizationTarget(String oeUriString, XmlElement synchronizationTargetXml, Boolean doneEditing)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.Model.Services.SynchronizationTargetsManager.SaveSynchronizationTarget(String oeUriString, XmlElement synchronizationTargetXml, Boolean doneEditing)   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.Model.Services.SynchronizationTargetsManager.SaveSynchronizationTarget(String oeUriString, XmlElement synchronizationTargetXml, Boolean doneEditing)
   at SyncInvokeSaveSynchronizationTarget(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have one or more CD environments configured in Topology Manager, but AM was unable to communicate with them.

Some things to check:

1. Which CD environments do you have? Are they all supposed to be enabled at this time? (if not, you can use Disable-TtmCdEnvironment to disable them)
2. Is the CM machine able to connect to the Discovery service of every one of those environments?
3. Do you have at least one Publication Mapping for each environment?
4. Are you using oAuth on your services and are your credentials set up correctly?

Comment: Thanks Peter We have one CD environment and after disabling that i was able to save Synchronization Target later i enabled it again although CM machine is able to connect to the Discovery service and we are using anonymous authentication in services and also Publication are Mapped to this environment.